# Android: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity A in `TabHost`, A `startActivityForResult(B)` then B `startActivityForResult(C)`.
The problem I meet is that:
In C when I setResult(RESULT_OK, intent), occur

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.hackingtrace.vancexu/com.hackingtrace.vancexu.task.B}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In B, I start C by

```
setTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), TaskTimeSet.class);
            i.putExtra(TasksDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date d = c.getTime();               
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String now = sdf.format(d);
            i.putExtra("date", now);

            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT_TIME);
        }
```

and in C, I setResult by

```
confirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("date", resultDate);

            int h = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
            int m = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            String time = "" +h+":"+m;
            Log.d(TAG, time);
            intent.putExtra("time", time);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

then in B I receive the result by

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I am in " + requestCode + resultCode);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_EDIT_TIME) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OK time set");
            String[] dateArr = intent.getStringExtra("date").split("-");
            String[] timeArr = intent.getStringExtra("time").split(":");
            int year = Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]);
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeArr[0]);
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(timeArr[1]);
            Log.d(TAG, ""+year+month+day+hour+minute);              
        }
    }
}
```

But I never get the "Log.d(TAG, ""+year+month+day+hour+minute);" run normally.

I have tried:
1:

```
if (getParent() == null) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            }
            else {
                getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            }
```

not work :(
2:

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

the error "java.lang.RuntimeException" not occur, but the requestCode and resultCode is 0 always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C I putExtra 2 string (resultDate and time), but I miss the point that resultDate may not be initialized when it is be put into intent. So I got the Error: `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Activity B is getting destroyed before C returns. One thing you can check is the "Dev Tools" app (It's among the app icons on most emulators and devices and in Settings on Ice Cream Sandwich labeled as "Developer Options") to make sure that the "Don't keep activities" option is not checked.

One thing you can do to verify that B is getting destroyed is to put a Log statement in Activity B's `onCreate` method. Then, when Activity C is launched from B, exit C by pushing the hardware Back button. This will destroy C (provided you haven't overridden the Back button), but it will not call B's `onCreate` unless B has been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, "it will not call B's onCreate" I have proofed. But what can I do to solve my problem? I found the  "Dev Tools" app in emulator but do not find "Don't keep activities" option

Comment: Depending on the Android version, it may read differently. Under 2.3.3, it's Dev Tools>Development Settings>"Immediately destroy activities". Make sure it's not checked. If `onCreate` is not getting called, then Activity B is not destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your watching, Brian.