# Cancel button click result in exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a button on the main activity A that once clicked will invoke another activity B.
On the activity B I have a cancel button and here is the error

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537,
>   result=-1, data=null} to activity
>   {com.mars.editor/com.mars.editor.MainActivity}

and the code in Main activity to call Activity B

```
Intent intent=new Intent(m_context,ActivityB.class);
                    if(intent!=null)
                    {
                        ItemClass ic=(ItemClass) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                        intent.putExtra("itemclass", ic);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
```

and the code for Cancel button

```
mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(getParent() == null)
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,null);    
                        else
                            getParent().setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,null);
                        finish();
                    }                   
                });
```

Comment: Check these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824660/androidfailure-delivering-result-resultinfo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782619/failure-delivering-result-resultinfo

Comment: `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,null);` the second param is null

Comment: what was your purpose of starting activity for result, when you are not returning any data from Activity B.

Comment: I have a button Save too if I click button save, data will be input into a listview in Main Activity

Comment: Sorry I had a but in my code, I fixed it. the above code causes no problem